# Hе работает код автокликера при введении промежутка кликов

Tags: python, pyautogui, pynput

```py
import pyautogui
from pynput.keyboard import *

#  ======== settings ========
ada = input('Speed of clicks in seconds: ')
delay = ada # in seconds
resume_key = Key.f4
pause_key = Key.f5
exit_key = Key.f10
#  ==========================

pause = True
running = True

def on_press(key):
    global running, pause

    if key == resume_key:
        pause = False
        print("[Resumed]")
    elif key == pause_key:
        pause = True
        print("[Paused]")
    elif key == exit_key:
        running = False
        print("[Exit]")


def display_controls():
    print("// - Settings: ")
    print("\t delay = " + str(delay) + ' sec' + '\n')
    print("// - Controls:")
    print("\t F4 = Resume")
    print("\t F5 = Pause")
    print("\t F10 = Exit")
    print("-----------------------------------------------------")
    print('Press F4 to start ...')


def main():
    lis = Listener(on_press=on_press)
    lis.start()

    display_controls()
    while running:
        if not pause:
            pyautogui.click(pyautogui.position())
            pyautogui.PAUSE = ada
    lis.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Проблема в том что при вводе значения кликар делает 2 клика и выключается, однако без регулируемого КПС(колличества кликов в секунду) он работает идеально.

Comment: У вас не КПС, а сколько секунд делать паузу (после чего именно - не очень понял). Интерфейс просто ждёт столько секунд, сколько вы ввели. Ну это так - навсткидку.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно заменить `ada = input('Speed of clicks in seconds: ')` на `ada = float(input('Speed of clicks in seconds: '))`